# Alternative to $element.isolateScope() when debugInfoEnabled is false?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using Angular 1.3.15, UI Bootstrap 0.12.1 and UI Router 0.2.13.

Given this markup:

```
<tabset type="tabs">
    <tab ui-sref="home.state1" ui-tabbed-state heading="tab1"></tab>
    <tab ui-sref="home.state2" ui-tabbed-state heading="tab2"></tab>
    <tab ui-sref="home.state3" ui-tabbed-state heading="tab3"></tab>
    <tab ui-sref="home.state4" ui-tabbed-state heading="tab4"></tab>
</tabset>
<ui-view />
```

and my custom `ui-tabbed-state` directive :

```
function uiTabbedStateDirective()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^tab',
        controller: [ '$element', '$state', function($element, $state) {
            var tabset = $element.controller('tabset');
            var tab    = $element.isolateScope();   // or $element.children().scope(); 
            var sref   = $element.attr('ui-sref');

            if (tabset && tab && sref && sref === $state.current.name)
                tabset.select(tab);
        }]
    };
}
```

I'm able to select the correct tab based on the current state/URL when navigating back and forth the app, refreshing, etc.

Trouble is, `$element.isolateScope()` (and `$element.scope()` for that matter) can only be used with Debug Data enabled. Is there any equivalent function or some workaround when Debug Data is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then, answering my own stupid question.

Short answer: RTFM.

Long answer: UI Router already has a `ui-sref-active` directive that does exactly that. OMG.

```
    <tabset type="tabs">
        <tab ui-sref="home.state1" ui-sref-active="active" heading="tab1"></tab>
        <tab ui-sref="home.state2" ui-sref-active="active" heading="tab2"></tab>
        <tab ui-sref="home.state3" ui-sref-active="active" heading="tab3"></tab>
        <tab ui-sref="home.state4" ui-sref-active="active" heading="tab4"></tab>
    </tabset>
```